# While trying to delete files in shell error occurs(syntax error: bad fd number)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Task: 
While executing shell script delete these two files (**Duge.Recenice.IB** and **Kratke.Recenice.IB** ) if they are existing , if not save an error in file **greske**

While trying to do that it says:

**Syntax error: bad fd number:**

rm Duge.Recenice.IB >& greske

rm Kratke.Recenice.IB >>& greske

It says on the second line error occurs, while trying to save to error msgs to **greske**.

Answer (score 0):

`>&` is messing around with file handles (to do things like redirect stderr to stdout via `2>&1`).

You just want to use the files, so

```
rm Duge.Recenice.IB > greske
rm Kratke.Recenice.IB >> greske
```

Should do it.

Comment: yes, but then an errors occurs on terminal while executing instead of 

being written in greske, and when I try to : cat greske notthing happens, 

errors should be written in greske, not being shown in terminal ://

Comment: You need to include the error messages. The code in my answer is valid. From memory there are shell settings that prevent you creating a new file with `>` You may need to redirect stderr to stdout `rm Duge.Recenice.IB > greske 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

> rm Duge.Recenice.IB >& greske
>   rm Kratke.Recenice.IB >>& greske

Presumably you are using `bash`. According to the bash manual, the format for [appending standard output and standard error](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) is:

```
          &>>word
```

Thus, you'd have to write

```
rm Kratke.Recenice.IB &>>greske
```

- but consider simply

```
rm Duge.Recenice.IB Kratke.Recenice.IB &>greske
```